# Google Maps JS API: Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (Safari Mac)

Tags: javascript, macos, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, safari

I've spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out why this is happening is MacOS Safari 12.1.2 with no luck, so I'm hoping somebody may have comes across it and know the answer.

**The Problem**

I am using the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 on a website build. Nothing too fancy, just some custom styling and some markers, clusters and infowindows. It works beautifully in Chrome, Firefox and IE, but in Safari the map appears blank.

I get the following error in the console:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: 
    TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'a:firstChild')
```

It references `ch - js:2393`

The JS is called at the bottom of the HTML file, so the DOM object should exist before it loads.

Test Link: https://site.303mullenlowe.agency/hawaiian-templates/

**The Code**

```
<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/_markerclusterer.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap" defer></script>
```

HTML:

```
<section class="panel panel--map">
    <h1 class="panel__heading panel__heading--map heading__section-name"><span>Find Your Local Hawaiian</span></h1>
    <div class="map__wrapper">
        <div id="mapAllProperties" class="map map--all-properties"></div>
        <div id="mapInset" class="map__inset">
            <a class="map__inset-link" href="https://www.cablebeachclub.com/">
                <img class="map__inset-image" src="images/map__inset--cable-beach@2x.png" alt="Cable Beach location">
                <p class="map__inset-label">Cable Beach Club Resort &amp; Spa, Broome</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
var map;
var markers = [];
var propertyContent = []

var properties = [
    ['Hawaiian\'s Bassendean', -31.903431, 115.95346, 'shopping-centre', 'https://bassendean.hawaiian.com.au', '2 West Rd, Bassendean', '(08) 9426 8893', 'bassendean'],
    ['Claremont Quarter', -31.98466, 115.78137, 'claremont-quarter', 'https://claremontquarter.com.au', '9 Bay View Terrace, Claremont', '(08) 9286 5885','claremont-quarter'],
    ['Darling Ridge Shopping Centre', -31.88545, 116.04222 ,'shopping-centre-generic', 'https://darlingridge.hawaiian.com.au', '309 Morrison Rd, Swan View', '(08) 9426 8888', 'darling-ridge'],
    ['Duncraig Shopping Centre', -31.83153, 115.76906, 'shopping-centre-generic', 'https://duncraig.hawaiian.com.au', '50 Marri Rd, Duncraig', '(08) 9426 8888', 'duncraig'],
    ['Hawaiian\'s Forrestfield', -31.98682, 116.00977, 'shopping-centre', 'https://forrestfield.hawaiian.com.au', '20 Strelitzia Ave, Forrestfield', '(08) 9426 8882', 'forrestfield'],
    ['Hawaiian\'s Melville', -32.03391, 115.7914, 'shopping-centre', 'https://melville.hawaiian.com.au', '380 Canning Hwy, Bicton', '(08) 9426 8886', 'melville'],
    ['Hawaiian\'s Mezz', -31.92091, 115.83946, 'shopping-centre', 'https://themezz.hawaiian.com.au', '148 Scarborough Beach Rd, Mount Hawthorn', '(08) 9426 8864', 'mezz'],
    ['Newpark Shopping Centre', -31.8356, 115.82978, 'shopping-centre-generic', 'https://newpark.hawaiian.com.au', '64 Marangaroo Dr, Girrawheen WA', '(08) 9426 8881', 'newpark'],
    ['Hawaiian\'s Noranda', -31.876545, 115.89535, 'shopping-centre', 'https://noranda.hawaiian.com.au', 'Benara Road, Noranda', '(08) 9426 8892', 'noranda'],
    ['Hawaiian\'s Park Centre', -31.98461, 115.90144, 'shopping-centre', 'https://parkcentre.hawaiian.com.au', '789 Albany Hwy, East Victoria Park', '(08) 9426 8891', 'park-centre'],
    ['Parmelia House', -31.95426, 115.85334, 'office-building', 'https://parmeliahouse.hawaiian.com.au', '191 St Georges Terrace, Perth', '(08) 9426 8888', 'parmelia-house'],
    ['London House', -31.95285, 115.85283, 'office-building', 'https://londonhouse.hawaiian.com.au', '216 St Georges Terrace, Perth', '(08) 9426 8888', 'london-house'],
    ['235 St Georges', -31.95386, 115.85099, 'office-building', '#', '235 St Georges Terrace, Perth', '(08) 9426 8888', '235-st-georges'],
    ['Parmelia Hilton', -31.95455, 115.8532, 'hotel-and-resort', '#', '14 Mill St, Perth', '(08) 9215 2000', 'parmelia-hilton'],
    ['Terrace Hotel', -31.9533, 115.85127, 'hotel-and-resort', '#', '237 St Georges Terrace, Perth', 'N/A', 'terrace-hotel']
];

function setMarkers(map) {

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        maxWidth: 300,
        pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-5,-10),
        zIndex: 1000
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        var property = properties[i];
        propertyContent.push('<div class="map__popup"><img src="images/map__location--' + property[7] + '.jpg" alt="Photo of ' + property[0] + '" class="map__popup-image"><h2 class="map__popup-name">' + property[0] + '</h2><p class="map__popup-address">' + property[5] + '</p><p class="map__popup-phone">Phone: ' + property[6] + '</p><a class="map__popup-link button" href="' + property[4] + '">Visit Website</a>    </div>');

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: property[1], lng: property[2]},
            map: map,
            title: property[0],
            icon: { url: 'images/map__marker--' + property[3] + '.png', size: new google.maps.Size(50, 61), origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 61) },
            info: propertyContent[i]
        })

        markers.push(marker);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.setContent(this.info);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });

    }

    var clusterOptions = {
        minimumClusterSize: 4,
        styles: [{
            anchorText: [50,0],
            textSize: 14,
            url: 'images/map__marker--cluster-1.png',
            width: 60,
            height: 70
        }]
    }

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);

}

function setBounds() {

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(null);

    for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
        var property = properties[i];

        bounds.extend({ lat: property[1], lng: property[2] })

        map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
        map.panToBounds(bounds);
        map.fitBounds(bounds, 0);
    }

}

function initMap() {

    var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(
        [
            {"elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{ "color": "#f1edde" }]},
            {"elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [{ "color": "#998A59" }]},
            {"elementType": "labels.text.stroke", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "administrative.land_parcel", "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "landscape", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{ "color": "#f1edde" }]},
            {"featureType": "poi", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "poi", "elementType": "labels.text", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "poi", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "poi.business", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "poi.park", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "road", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{ "color": "#e2d7be" }]},
            {"featureType": "road", "elementType": "labels.icon", "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "road.arterial", "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{ "color": "#e2d7be" }]},
            {"featureType": "road.highway", "elementType": "labels", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "road.local", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "transit", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "transit.line", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "transit.station", "elementType": "geometry", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]},
            {"featureType": "water", "elementType": "geometry.fill", "stylers": [{ "color": "#ffffff" }]},
            {"featureType": "water", "elementType": "labels.text.fill", "stylers": [{ "visibility": "off" }]}
        ],
        {name: 'Styled Map'}
    )

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapAllProperties'), {
       center: {lat: -31.900675, lng: 115.849444},
       zoom: 12,
       mapTypeControl: false,
       streetViewControl: false,
       rotateControl: false,
       fullscreenControl: false,
       zoomControl: true,
       mapTypeControlOptions: {
           mapTypeIds: ['roadmap','styled_map'],
       }
   });

   map.mapTypes.set('styled_map', styledMapType);
   map.setMapTypeId('styled_map');
   setMarkers(map);
   setBounds(map);

   var mapInset = document.getElementById('mapInset');  
   map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(mapInset);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It turns out, even though my 3 instances of `initMap` were inside separate `if statements`, Safari was just running the last one, not the one specific for the page it was on. The other browsers seemed to figure out what was required fine.

The solution was to give each `initMap` function a unique name.